# Numpy Memory Error with rather small array: Unable to allocate 359. MiB for an array on Win 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, memory, data-science

I'm currently trying to build an elm using code from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-an-extreme-learning-machine-in-python-91d1e8958599) , however the problem I encounter is not specific to elm: when running the line

```
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(train.values[:, 1:])
```

using the sklearn MinMaxScaler I get the following error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 359. MiB for an array with shape (60000, 784) and data type float64
```

It tells me that it cannot allocate 359. MiB for that relatively small matrix. The lines before that are only for additional setup, as in the example from the link, so nothing should max out the memory usage. I have plenty of RAM (16GB, about 10GB unused when running the code) so I don't understand what is going on. I guess that it is somehow not allowed to use more RAM but I don't know why or what to do against that.

I'm running the code on Windows 10 without a VM. Both, using the console and running it in PyCharm produce this error.

Any ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: You should be using 64-bit Python for this; have you verified that you're using that and not a 32-bit version?

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel stupid, but I somehow used an older installation of 32-bit python and did not think about it. (Should I delete the question now or close it somehow? I'm new to posting)

Comment: If you want, you can post your solution an answer to your own post and accept it, so that others would be able to find this solution in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 64-bit Python

(See comments beneath question)

The answer is that I had a 32-bit python interpreter on both my path and the PyCharm run configuration. Changing that to a 64-bit version fixed it, so it was less of an issue of running out of memory rather than using float64 with a 32-bit interpreter.